# Check if user has AppleWatch connected without prompting the watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

We are using *Google Analytics*, and want to know how many of our users are in possession of an *AppleWatch*. I have searched Stack for answers, and the recurring answer is to use this:

```
if WCSession.isSupported() { // check if the device support to handle an Apple Watch
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession() // activate the session

        if session.paired { // Check if the iPhone is paired with the Apple Watch
                // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that it prompts the user to *'accept'* the app on the *AppleWatch*. Granted, the if-statement is true wether or not the user accepts, but I don't want the user to get their hopes up, thinking the app supports *AppleWatch*. I simply want to know if the user has an AppleWatch, I don't want to use it. Yet.
Is there a property on the iOS-device that can be accessed to show if the user has or ever had an *AppleWatch* connected, without prompting the user through the Watch?

Comment: Good question. But I doubt it - it flies in the face of most iOS security models to allow for that kind of global access.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use (Push)Notifications, since there is no need to develop a native applewatch app to receive notifications on the watch. For example i receive "whats app messages" on my watch, but it does not have any native app on the watch either.

In your watchkit extension ExtensionDelegate.m you can handle provided answers to the push message separately. [Link to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1)

This would be a(nother) approach, where you have to be creative!

Comment: But how does this help me? Can I track where the notification will be sent, but then not actually send it? Either I didn't understand your answer, or you didn't understand my question.. I want to know if the iPhone is connected with an AppleWatch **without showing anything** on the Watch.

Comment: Probably bit of both, I edited my answer above to be a bit more concrete. I was assuming you are using an iOS App with Google Analytics and your app supports remote notifications as well.

Comment: Sadly there are no notifications for this app. Anyway, this will also assume that the user accepts notifications from the app, and my question is towards checking for an AppleWatch, regardless of notification-settings. But it was a good idea (if it works)!