# Check if Apple Watch is not currently connected

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I am trying to detect if a user's Apple watch is currently active using this code:

```
if WCSession.isSupported()  {
  let session = WCSession.default
  session.delegate = self
  session.activate() 
}
```

But even after I power off the watch, I get a callback to `session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?)` with `activationState == .activated`.

Is this expected?  Is there any way to actually check if the watch and the iPhone are connected?

**EDIT:** I also note that if I run the same code inside a simulator, I get the exact same callback with activationState == .activated, yet isPaired == false.  It sounds to me like `.activated` basically is the default state.  I'm not even sure how to get `.deactivated`

**EDIT 2:**  I actually do not have a WatchKit extension and would rather not create one for simplicity.  I am simply trying to detect if a paired watch is in range, powered on and communicating so I can tell if my apps local notifications might be delivered to the watch.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I understand what you're asking now. The issue is that if you check `isPaired` you get true, even if the app is launched and the watch is not connected.

Example:

```
import WatchConnectivity

func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if WCSession.isSupported() {
      let session = WCSession.default
      session.delegate = self
      session.activate()
    }

    return true
  }
}

extension AppDelegate: WCSessionDelegate {
  func session(
    _ session: WCSession,
    activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState,
    error: Error?) {

    switch session.activationState {

    case .notActivated:
      print("Session no activated")
    case .inactive:
      print("Session inactive")
    case .activated:
      print("Session activated")
    @unknown default:
      break
    }

    if let err = error {
      print("ERROR: \(err.localizedDescription)")
    }

    if session.isPaired {
      print("Current phone is paired to an apple watch!")
    }

    print("reachable: \(session.isReachable)")
  }

  func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
    print("Session just became inactive")
  }

  func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
    print("session did deactivate")
  }
}
```

This results in the following output with the watch powered on or off

```
Session activated
Current phone is paired to an apple watch!
reachable: false
```

Note `isReachable` is always false because you don't have a watch extension.

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672447/check-if-user-has-applewatch-connected-without-prompting-the-watch) there is no solution to this problem. I don't think you can determine this information without a watch extension / app.

Also note that you cannot access the [WKInterfaceDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice) outside of the watch app.

Comment: Thanks.  So isPaired does tell me if a watch is paired, but not if it is present and connected to the phone.  I tried isReachable but it always returns false, even if the watch is connected, probably because I have no WatchKit extension.  I am simply trying to detect if a watch is present.  I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, trying to understand... What is the difference between `isPaired` and "present and connected to the phone"? Take a look at these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631060/how-to-track-in-ios-app-if-user-has-apple-watch-without-watch-extension) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457558/check-if-iphone-is-paired-with-apple-watch)

Comment: Based on my tests, the isPaired flag just indicates of the user has paired the phone with a watch at some point in the past.  It doesn't tell you anything about whether the watch is powered up near the phone -- isPaired returns true even if the phone is powered off or is out of radio range.  I am looking for an indicator of whether the phone is actively connected to the watch. (The iOS watch app has this indicator in the UI)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for: `isPaired` property of `WCSession`.

After calling `activateSession` and getting callback you can check if Watch is paired there.

If you need to know if app is installed on Watch - check `isWatchAppInstalled`.

Comment: Thanks, isPaired does tell me if the phone is paired with a watch, but I want to know if that watch is present and active.  See edit in question to clarify.

Comment: @davidgyoung isPaired is exactly that

Comment: Unfortunately, my tests show that isPaired returns true regardless of whether the phone is physically present or powered on.